# How to send large request to MySQL From VBA

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, adodb

I'm using ADODB in VBA to send request to my MySQL server.

```
conn.Open
conn.Execute Command
conn.Close
```

It works fine for small requests, but when Command's size is bigger than 255 characters, it is truncated to its first 255 characters.

Is there some kind of limitation ? Is there a way to expand it ?

Is there a more efficient way to send large queries to MySQL ?

Comment: Try to declare your `Command` as a Variant as described in this [thread](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?570066-Error-with-MySQL-query-string-longer-than-255-characters)

Answer (score 1):

Using the MySQL ODBC driver 5.1.11 I have sent several commands over 1024 bytes in length to MySQL without any problems. What version of ADODB are you running and what have you defined your "Command" variable as ?